# BatteryManager BroadcastReceiver not detecting charging state

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am currently trying to change an icon everytime the phone is plugged in either via usb or ac . I set up a broadcast receiver in the manifest to try and update the UI whenever the charging state changes.

Here is my onReceive method and manifest:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
}

    <receiver android:name=".BatteryHelper" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

which no matter what all the booleans return as false regardless of where I plug it. I tried calling this method in the onRecieve method and for some reason it works:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
}
```

and this returns true. Can anyone spot why my onReceive isn't working yet the isConnected method is?

Comment: If your goal is to know if the device is connected to a power source, only check for usb or ac plugged state. EXTRA_STATUS will be BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING when the battery is fully charged even if the power source is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Intent` delivered to your Receiver for those actions does not carry any extras. Battery stats are carried in a sticky `Intent`, which allows apps to request the necessary information at any time, without having to wait for a regular Broadcast. You will need to get the stats you want from the sticky `Intent` like you've done in your `isConnected()` method.

Comment: But android literally recommends doing it that way http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html I took the code directly from there

Comment: Read that example again carefully, and compare it to your Receiver's code. You're trying to get extras from the `Intent` passed into the `onReceive()` method. The example explicitly shows that the `Intent` used is the sticky `Intent` obtained from passing `null` for the first parameter in the `registerReceiver()` method, as you've done in `isConnected()`.

Comment: No sweat! Glad to help.

Comment: Hey mike, I am having some more issues. So I figured out what that issue was. I don't know how I can structure this properly so I figured I would ask you. I have a class that sort of acts as a controller of certain components of my app. Is there anyway to pass information from my listener when it receives a battery change intent to the controller oject. My issue is I try passing in information but it turns out that the BroadcastReciever always uses the empty constructor when creating it which makes it impossible to pass anything to it since I am not creating it.  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of class is it? If it's an Activity, you can't instantiate it directly; the system handles creating Activities. You'll need to pass any data as extras on the Intent you use to start the Activity.

Comment: Its not an activity, its just a class that I use to update UI components dynamically. I want to be able to pass in an updated isCharging boolean to that class whenever the broadcast receiver notices it is happening. Sorry to bother its just I have tried doing this for 3 days and I am making no progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57887/discussion-between-bionicsheep-and-mike-m).